# Why unit test is failing although it contains all the values I am testing

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, nunit, xunit, nsubstitute

This is the fail error I get on my xUnit with NSubstitute:

```
Xunit.Sdk.ContainsException
Assert.Contains() Failure
Not found: Please send my Password.
Name: Blake Lively
Phone: 7021102502
I Lost my pass, Help
In value:  Blake Lively
```

And this is what I have in my unit test code:

```
    var whatsInIt = msg.Notes;

    Assert.Contains(msg.Notes, "Blake Lively");
    Assert.Contains(msg.Notes, "7021102502");
    Assert.Contains(msg.Notes, "Help");
```

I wrote that `whatsInIt`  to put a break point and see what is there before asserting it, so the value I see in is is this:

```
Please send my Password.
Name: Blake Lively
Phone: 7021102502
I Lost my pass, Help
```

So why is it still failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your parameters backwards.  Try this instead:

```
var whatsInIt = msg.Notes;

Assert.Contains("Blake Lively", msg.Notes);
Assert.Contains("7021102502", msg.Notes);
Assert.Contains("Help", msg.Notes);
```